# How can I get the Stateless Grain from Specific Silo (Orleans 2.0)

Tags: c#, orleans

Have 3 silos on server and have Stateless grain

```
[StatelessWorker(1)] // max 1 activation per silo
public class MyLonelyWorkerGrain : ILonelyWorkerGrain
{
 ...
}
```

So create 1(Max) grain per silo. Is there any way force to get the Grain from specific silo?

```
GrainFactory.GetGrain<ILonelyWorkerGrain>(0); //?????
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Orleans documentation](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/grains/stateless_worker_grains.html):

> When the [StatelessWorker] attribute is applied to a grain class, it indicates to the Orleans runtime that grains of that class should be treated as Stateless Worker grains. Stateless Worker grains have the following properties that make their execution very different from that of normal grain classes.
>
> 1. The Orleans runtime can and will create multiple activations of a Stateless Worker grain on different silos of the cluster.
> 2. Requests made to Stateless Worker grains ***are always executed locally, that is on the same silo where the request originated***, either made by a grain running on the silo or received by the silo's client gateway. ***Hence, calls to Stateless Worker grains from other grains or from client gateways never incur a remote message***.
> 3. The Orleans Runtime automatically creates additional activations of a Stateless Worker grain if the already existing ones are busy. The maximum number of activations of a Stateless Worker grain the runtime creates per silo is limited by default by the number of CPU cores on the machine, unless specified explicitly by the optional maxLocalWorkers argument.
> 4. Because of 2 and 3, Stateless Worker grain activations are not individually addressable. Two subsequent requests to a Stateless Worker grain may be processed by different activations of it.